# Python - For loops with multiple indices

Tags: python, for-loop, rhino3d

I'm trying to access multiple items in a list as they relate to one another.
I would like to access list item 0 and 1, item 1 & 2.
I'm familiar with for loops, but only accessing

```
list = [A, B, C, D, E, F] etc.
for i in list:
     print(i)
     print (i+1)
```

Result:

AB
BC
CD
DE
EF

I would also prefer to not get F'null' or "FA" as a tail.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.pairwise` was designed just for this

```
from itertools import pairwise

for a, b in pairwise(mylist):
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just zip the collection with itself offset by 1:

```py
mylist = list('ABCDEF')

for a, b in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):
    print(a, b)

A B
B C
C D
D E
E F
```